# Neo4j Cypher query to return one row per node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the data:

- `Adam` bought a `Honda Civic` in `2006`
- `Adam` bought a `Bowling Ball` in `2008`
- `Adam` bought a `Tennis Racket` in `2010`
- `Adam` bought a `Toyota Camry` in `2013`
- `Adam` bought a `Hiking Shoes` in `2015`

I want to be able to query for any given time and see what the last sporting equipment and car Adam bought. The `THING` nodes have a `type` property (`car`, `sporting equipment`, etc).

This works...

```
MATCH (person:Person {name: {name})
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[bought:BOUGHT]-(thing:THING)
WHERE bought.date <= {date}
RETURN *
ORDER BY thing.date DESC
```

...but it returns everything he's ever bought before the specified date. I could just grab the first row for each `type` in my application, but this is a contrived example, and in reality my actual application could see thousands of entries like this before aging off.

If I put...

```
LIMIT 1
```

...at the end, then I only get the last bought `THING` (as opposed to the last one of each type).

How can I build a query that will provide me with something like:

Query: Tell me about `Adam` and the last things he bought as of `2011`?

Response:

```
person                  | bought           | thing
{name: 'Adam', age: 38} | {date: 2010}     | {type: 'sporting equipment', name: 'Tennis Racket'}
{name: 'Adam', age: 38} | {date: 2006}     | {type: 'car', name: 'Honda Civic'}
```

Comment: Do you know what all possible types are? If you don't, then you would have to look through every single thing he's bought (according to the date ranges of your query) and compare your type strings to figure out if you've processed that type already or not. I would seriously consider making labels of all possible types, and if you need to treat them as more generic "things" later, double-label them as both :Thing and the type label. That opens up options. Also, if order is vital to your queries, you may want to consider modeling his purchases as linked lists, each with a specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by `thing.type`:

```
MATCH (person:Person {name: {name}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[bought:BOUGHT]-(thing:THING)
WHERE bought.date <= {date}
WITH person, 
     thing, 
     bought ORDER by bought.date DESC
WITH person, 
     thing.type as type, 
     HEAD(collect([thing, bought])) as tmp
RETURN person, 
       tmp[1] as bought, 
       tmp[0] as thing
```

Comment: A couple minor tweaks for my actual domain and it works great. Thanks for the major point in the right direction!